# php/mysql How to display images in an online forum

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

I've asked this question before, but got no answers, so I'm asking it again but this time, I will be more specific.
I have an online forum which I created from scratch with php and mysql, I've implemented the image uploading part naming the image by the topic id, from the posts table, Now I'm having problems displaying the images by pulling the name and the extension from the image table and attaching it to the topic id to be displayed. Now this is the code snippet for displaying topics (viewtopic.php)

```
$sql = "
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS p.id
                         , p.subject
                         , p.body
                         , p.date_posted
                         , p.date_updated
                         , u.name as author
                         , u.id as author_id
                         , u.signature as sig
                         , c.count as postcount
                         , p.forum_id as forum_id
                         , f.forum_moderator as 'mod'
                         , p.update_id
                         , u2.name as updated_by 
                      FROM forum_forum f 
                      JOIN forum_posts p 
                        ON f.id = p.forum_id 
                      JOIN forum_users u 
                        ON u.id = p.author_id 
                      LEFT 
                      JOIN forum_users u2 
                        ON u2.id = p.update_id 
                      LEFT 
                      JOIN forum_postcount c 
                        ON u.id = c.user_id 
                     WHERE $topicid IN (p.topic_id,p.id) 
                     ORDER 
                        BY p.topic_id
                         , p.date_posted 
                     LIMIT $start,$limit;
                     ";
$result = mysqli_query($sql, $conn)
or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fecth_array($result) )
{
echo "<p>($body) . "</p>";
  echo $sig;

}
```

Now after echo ($body) if I run this query;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE name = '$name'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($sql) or die('Could not SELECT image data ' . mysql_error());
while ($therow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$image_name = $therow["name"] ;
$ext = $therow["extension"];
}

?>
<img src="images/<?php echo $image_name.$ext;  ?>" >
```

Help me, how do i get images to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Try replace this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fecth_array($result) )
{
    echo "<p>($body) . "</p>";
    echo $sig;
}
```

to

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) )
{
    echo "<p>($body)" . "</p>";
    echo $sig;
}
```

and this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE name = '$name'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($sql) or die('Could not SELECT image data ' . mysql_error());
while ($therow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $image_name = $therow["name"] ;
    $ext = $therow["extension"];
}
?>
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE name = '$name'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($sql) or die('Could not SELECT image data ' . mysql_error());
while ($therow = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $image_name = $therow["name"];
    $ext = $therow["extension"];
}
?>
```